# How do I find the correct bridge to replace one that has worn out?

Tags: electric-guitar, repair

My guitar (Ibanez AXD71) has a les paul (tune-o-matic) style bridge, and one of the screws used to adjust intonation has come loose from the end of the bridge. Since the screw is no longer fixed to the bridge, the string tension pulls the saddle as far towards the neck as it will go. I believe that I need to replace the bridge in order to set the intonation, but I know that Ibanez guitars sometimes have weird (metric) measurements that sometimes makes replacement parts designed for American guitars incompatible with them. As in, a bridge designed for a Gibson guitar that uses Imperial measurements might not fit.

Compounding this, Ibanez Artcore guitars change every model year, so the chance of me finding a compatible bridge advertised to fit this model is slim. How do I measure to find a bridge that will fit my guitar?

Comment: do you have a shop that has a luthier that you can take this to for help? i would think they would have experience with this and be able to order you the correct part if needed.

Comment: If I can't figure it out I can consult a professional, sure, but I'd greatly prefer to figure out how to order the right part on my own. Guitar maintenance/repair is as much a part of my hobby as playing the thing :)

Comment: i get that. if there is a part number on the bridge, this may help: http://www2.ibanez.com/parts